# Theme Development Admin Area

Tags: themes, admin, customization

I think I start to develope themes now (after using WordPress for years now). 
I have a question: How can I integrate a custom dashboard like this I found here:[image]

Thank you for your help. Greetings
Steph

Comment: When you say dashboard, you mean an admin dashboard? Why would you want a custom one? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: clients should easily work on their site....

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to modify the Dashboard.

It's recommended to create custom post types for content organisation and a top-level feature plugin for more complex options and settings. You can also use the Customizer to allow theme changes. A theme might already have these settings, so you could add some meta boxes with general help and how-to tutorials. You can also change the admin theme.

Note that a major WordPress version is coming really soon - 5.0 - and a feature plugin to make the admin theme dark is already submitted for consideration in core. Any Dashboard-changing plugin you might find, could be invalidated by this major version.

Also note that any Dashboard-changing plugin you might find is usually based on hacks and styling overrides.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this plugin:
[custom dashboard](https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-dashboard/) to design a new dashboard in the frontend of your site, you  also can customize the main dashboard yourself. [Customize your wordpress dashboard](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-client-dashboard-in-wordpress/) give you good start point on this matter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about this Plugins. But how can i Integrate this in my theme? Snippet in Funktions.php? Or is there an other way. So you know any snippet for this? Thanks

Comment: Look at :https://buffercode.com/category/name/frontend-dashboard I hope videos on this site be beneficial for you